# Solo obtengo el último dato de una consulta / Android

Tags: php, mysql, android, android-volley

estoy enfrentando un problema con la librería `Volley` estoy tratando de obtener todos los datos de una consulta a `MySQL` con `PHP` y solo me obtiene el último dato, cuando le seteo el resultado en un System.out.print en el logcat si aparecen todos los datos al igual que en un `Toast` pero al momento de setear los datos en un `TextView` solo me trae el último, cual es la forma correcta de obtenerlos por ejemplo si son 3 datos los que quiero obtener que se creen 3 `TextViews` y se agreguen a esos 3 `TextViews` de forma **dinámica**, esto es lo que tengo por el momento.

```
public void obtenerOpciones() {

    String url = "MI_URL";
    System.out.println(url);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Platos");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        listaOpciones.add(
                                new Opciones(
                                 jsonObject1.getString("nombre_producto"),
                                 jsonObject1.getInt("id_producto_comp")));

                        for (int j = 0; j < listaOpciones.size(); j++ ) {
                            opciones = listaOpciones.get(j).getNombreProducto();
                            opcionesTV.setText(opciones);
                        }

                    }

                    adaptador = new AdaptadorOpciones(ObtenerOpciones.this, listaOpciones);
                    rvOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace
    ) {};

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Aqui es donde le trato de setear un `TextView` los datos que contenga la consulta:

```
for (int j = 0; j < listaOpciones.size(); j++ ) {
                            opciones = listaOpciones.get(j).getNombreProducto();
                            opcionesTV.setText(opciones);
                        }
```

Pero como lo había mencionado solo me setea el ultimo registro, espero alguien me pueda instruir si necesitan mas código por favor decirme tengo los adaptadores y toda la lógica implementada así como también lo que quiero lograr por si tienen dudas del código, de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes operar el `setText()` dentro del bucle, pues el `TextView` se quedará con el último elemento, como de hecho ocurre.

Puedes definir un `StringBuilder`, para ir recogiendo los valores y luego usar ese `StringBuilder` para setear los datos, **fuera del bucle**.

Por ejemplo:

```
                    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("");
                    for (int j = 0; j < listaOpciones.size(); j++ ) {
                        sb.append(listaOpciones.get(j).getNombreProducto());
                    }
                    opcionesTV.setText(sb.toString());
```

#### P. D. :

Dado que en la pregunta dejas caer la idea de crear tres `TextView`, debo advertirte que esto no es una buena idea. Si lo que quieres es mostrar una especie de lista con cada opción es mejor que uses un `RecyclerView`. En ese caso, poblarías el RV con los elementos que lees en el bucle, olvidándote de `setText()`, pues RecyclerView es otra cosa y tiene su propio modo de funcionamiento. Es el elemento adecuado para manejar listas. Pero si es un elemento para lectura simple (algo así como concatenar contenido para mostrar al usuario) un solo `TextView` es suficiente. Considera que un `TextView` es una vista, y que si los creas de forma indiscriminada estarás sobre-cargando la UI sin necesidad.

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta esto era lo que buscaba, por el momento esto es lo que necesito pero gracias por el consejo lo tomare el cuenta.